# how to measure mosfet impedance in LTspice?

Tags: power, mosfet, amplifier, impedance-matching

I am trying to design a 13.56MHz 20W class E amplifier based on a TI app note [this](https://e2e.ti.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-discussions-components-files/667/3348.appnote_5F00_trf796x_5F00_pwramp_5F00_4w.pdf). On page 5, it say "FET(IRF510)’s gate impedance is 14-j26", which I should match impedance to my driver output. However, I am confused how to measure IRF510's gate input impedance, for example, in LTspice. Should I use either of the two test circuit in below picture? The first one gives 8.7-j34.9, and the second one gives 3.8-j28.8. None of them the same with the value mentioned in TI's doc(14-j26). Is the spice model in LTspice is different, or my test circuit is wrong?
[image: IRF510 gate impedance]

Comment: *which I should match impedance to my driver output* **Why ?** Is that needed and if so, explain why. Do you know how a class E amplifier works ? If not, read this: http://rfic.eecs.berkeley.edu/~niknejad/ee242/pdf/eecs242_class_EF_PAs.pdf You're now "stuck" on finding that input impedance without realizing that....

Comment: Regarding the 2 impedance test circuits, you're biasing the MOSFET differently so it is no surprise that you get different values. As a test, replace the MOSFET with a capacitor (optionally with a parallel or series resistance) and check if you simulate the correct impedance value.

Comment: And another thing, the gate impedance will be different when the MOSFET is used in the amplifier because of the Cgd capacitor and the larger signal in that node due to the Miller effect.